After installing Kubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, I cannot double-click to open any files on desktop. Please help?
I have to do a right-click then select open with app. Is there a way to get the double-click to open functionality back? FYI, I can use double-click to open after I access the files from Dolphin.

There is a bug in Plasma desktop (patched in ver. 6.0, while Kubuntu 24.04 uses 5.27.11) that makes the delay between clicks on desktop icons incorrect for monitors with a higher refresh rate (120hz+).
Consider switching your display refresh rate to something closer to 60hz or wait for an update. If there is an such an option, try changing the double click timings manually (citation needed :D).
